# Firebase Crashlytics for Flutter events are not showing up on dashboard

Tags: flutter, firebase, crashlytics

I am setting up Firebase Crashlytics and I see in the dashboard that my app is linked.

However when I try to force crash the app, I see this in my logs

```
Another exception was thrown: Exception: testing crashlytics
D/FirebaseCrashlytics(18620): Recorded on-demand fatal events: 6
D/FirebaseCrashlytics(18620): Dropped on-demand fatal events: 0
D/FirebaseCrashlytics(18620): Handling uncaught exception "io.flutter.plugins.firebase.crashlytics.FlutterError: Exception: testing crashlytics. Error thrown while handling a gesture." from thread pool-22-thread-5
D/FirebaseCrashlytics(18620): No userId set for session 6452F9A2010C000748BCA081BEDE22C4
D/FirebaseCrashlytics(18620): No userId set for session 6452F9A2010C000748BCA081BEDE22C4
D/FirebaseCrashlytics(18620): Opening a new session with ID 6452FA320223000848BCA081BEDE22C4
D/FirebaseCrashlytics(18620): Crashlytics automatic data collection ENABLED by API.
D/FirebaseCrashlytics(18620): Logging app exception event to Firebase Analytics
D/FirebaseCrashlytics(18620): Skipping logging Crashlytics event to Firebase, no Firebase Analytics
D/FirebaseCrashlytics(18620): Enqueueing report: 6452F9A2010C000748BCA081BEDE22C4
D/FirebaseCrashlytics(18620): Queue size: 0
D/FirebaseCrashlytics(18620): Closing task for report: 6452F9A2010C000748BCA081BEDE22C4
D/FirebaseCrashlytics(18620): Crashlytics report successfully enqueued to DataTransport: 6452F9A2010C000748BCA081BEDE22C4
D/FirebaseCrashlytics(18620): Sending report through Google DataTransport: 6452F9A2010C000748BCA081BEDE22C4
D/FirebaseCrashlytics(18620): Deleted report file: /data/user/0/com.recorahealth.members.staging/files/.com.google.firebase.crashlytics.files.v2:com.recorahealth.members.staging/priority-reports/6452F9A2010C000748BCA081BEDE22C4
```

I don't see anything in my dashboard -- even after a full day.

What stood out to me was this:

```
Skipping logging Crashlytics event to Firebase, no Firebase Analytics
```

I'm assuming I might need firebase_analytics? Otherwise, I'm at a loss.

EDIT: I added `firebase_analytics` but nothing is showing up on my dashboard, unfortunately.

Comment: Not sure whether its still the case but I recall we had to add the native sdks as well. How to configure this https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android.